# How can I use the one function variable to another function in php or the WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have retrieved a value from the ajax request stored in the **$passValue** in the **my_ajax_req**. Now I am trying to use the value of the variable in the another function **wpsln_log_wp_user_login**. I have written the following codes to that. But this is in vain. I have searched how I can do this. It is the one ans. But this is not working. Please help me why the **$passValue** is not working in the **wpsln_log_wp_user_login**.

```
function my_ajax_req() {
    global $passValue;
    $passValue = $_POST['passVal'];
    die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_my_req', 'my_ajax_req' );
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_req', 'my_ajax_req' );

function wpsln_log_wp_user_login( $user_user_login, $user ) {
  global $passValue;
  echo $passValue;

}
add_action( 'wp_login', 'wpsln_log_wp_user_login', '60', 2 );
```

Comment: Convert it into `sessions` Like `$_SESSION['passVal'] = $passValue;` so you can use session variable in `wpsln_log_wp_user_login`

Comment: I am new in php. So please how and where I will put the codes, describe me. I do not get how should do. I have tried it in the my_ajax_req function as `$passValue = $_SESSION['passVal']`. But it did not working.

Comment: if you try echo `$passValue = $_POST['passVal'];` what does it print ? does it echo something ??

Comment: Yes, it is echoing. I tried it in the ajax success. But it does not work in the function `wpsln_log_wp_user_login`.

Answer (score 0):

Use Sessions if global scope is not working. as I told you in comments
i used `die('Call');` to check if it is echoing the data which session variable holds.

```
function my_ajax_req()
{
    session_start();
    $passValue = $_POST['passVal'];
    $_SESSION['passValue'] = $passValue;
    die();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_my_req', 'my_ajax_req');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_req', 'my_ajax_req');

function wpsln_log_wp_user_login($user_user_login, $user)
{
    $passValue = $_SESSION['passValue'];
    echo $passValue;
    die('Call'); // Remove die when it works 
    // do your further code here if require.
}

add_action('wp_login', 'wpsln_log_wp_user_login', '60', 2);
```

Comment: Yet it is not working? Please seek another way to do it. I am in great need to that. I am appreciating to you to help me. If you help me successfully I will be grateful to forever.

Comment: @ChayanBiswas i saw your edit , you need to remove `die('Call');` change this `add_action('wp_login', 'wpsln_log_wp_user_login', '60', 2);` to this `add_action('wp_login', 'wpsln_log_wp_user_login', 10, 2);`

Comment: have you checked it? This is not working yet. I am getting very confused. Please check it locally. And then suggest me what should I do?